# Why is Wi-Fi connection speed slower than LAN?

Tags: wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop, wifi-configuration, internet-speed

[modem setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOpsN.jpg)On my laptop, the Wi-Fi connection speed is so much slower than the LAN connection.

I have reset my router, I have even reinstalled the drivers and Windows, but the problem is still remains.

I have a Lenovo 80VR device, and no other devices in our home have same problem and the Wi-Fi and LAN have same speed on other devices.

Comment: "so much slower" is not specific. What is the actual rate (e.g., from speedtest.net)? What ate the specs of the WiFi modem in the Lenovo 80VR? What band is it using?

Comment: A Wired LAN connection is a solid connection that will use the full capacity of the wire. While Wi-Fi speed/bandwidth depends on a lot in your proximity, interference from other Wi-Fi networks or other machinery in the vicinity, and much more. That's even if the router is capable of higher speed Wi-Fi.

Comment: the wifi speed, is about 20% lan speed. just in my laptop this problem seems. other devices have same lan and wifi speed

Comment: @s.morteza It seems like you just ignored the questions DrMoishe Pippik asked. It is impossible to answer your question without detailed information and measurements that only you can provide.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik sorry for late, i have tp-link 150 mb/s router that supports b,g,n channels and it's so close to laptop, about 40cm. my lenovo have standard realtech wifi with b,g,n support. net connection with wifi is 1 mb/s and with lan is 8 mb/s. other laptops in my home, doesn't have this problem, wifi and lan, have same speed on others.

Answer (score 0):

WiFi is shared medium, wire is point to point.
• Two wifi access point on same (on next to each other) channel will interfere thus maximum bandwidth is limited.
• Your wireless adapter, your router, or just a device on your network may have outdated standard (b, bg, bgn). Having a 802.11g device on a 802.11n network will slow down all the devices on the net supporting higher standards.
• Your router may just be crappy (Processor not able to handle all the data youre trying to push trough it)

Anyway you didn't provide enough context to let us tell you more, stuff like:
• Maximum internet speed
• Router supported standard (or, at least, model)
• Difference between wire speed and wifi speed
• Environment where the router is installed (single home, condo, office block)
• How many interfering network you have (`netsh wlan show all` will provide some data to tell)
• Distance between Router and laptop